# Does the Endurance co-op DLC allows for split-screen play?

Tags: rise-of-the-tomb-raider

I just want to know if the Endurance co-op DLC is online only or if it's possible to play with both players on the same TV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the co-op is online only. There is no split screen integrated.

Answer (score -1):

If you go on the ps4 store it says that you can play 2 player

Comment: Providing a source (like a link to the Playstation store (the desktop one) ) will make your answer a better one. It makes sure that its 100% accurate.

Comment: Playing 2 player does not necessarily imply splitscreen.